# Custom generic response with Ktor client

Tags: generics, jackson, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, ktor-client

I am trying to write a custom, "Ktor-client Converter for wrapped responses", in a generic class internally like here [Medium Link](https://medium.com/hackernoon/retrofit-converter-for-wrapped-responses-8919298a549c)

Example:
Suppose an api gives following response,

```
    @Serializable
    @SerialName("DataResponseContainer")
    data class DataResponseContainer<out T>(val data: T?,
                                            val statusCode: Int?,
                                            val message: String?)
```

Api Response format::

```
    {
       "data" : {...}
       "statusCode" : 0
       "message" : null
    }
```

for which we write the client as follows,

```
    httpClient.get("splash").body<DataResponseContainer<SplashEntity>>()
```

now, i need only, "data" object, so i want to write it like,

```
    httpClient.get("splash").body<SplashEntity>()
    httpClient.get("login").body<LoginEntity>()
```

Also, i tried to write custom plugin but i don't know how to do it,

```
  val DataTransformationPlugin = 
  createClientPlugin("DataTransformationPlugin") {

transformResponseBody { response, content, requestedType ->

    val mapper = ObjectMapper()
    if(response.status.isSuccess()) {
        try {
            val user: ResponseWrapper<*> = mapper.readValue(response.bodyAsText(), ResponseWrapper::class.java)
            //Now i want to deserialize it to get only "data" in called body
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            content
        }

    } else
        content
}
```

}

Response Modal:

```
data class SplashEntity(val lang: String, val type: String)
data class LoginEntity(val id: Int, val role: String)
```

Response for splash:

```
{
  data: {
    "lang": "en",
    "type": "owner",
    
  },
  "statusCode": 200,
  "message": ""
}
```

Response for login:

```
{
  data: {
    "id": 1244,
    "role": "admin",
    
  },
  "statusCode": 200,
  "message": ""
}
```

Comment: Please post the code as as text, and not an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual, issue was the deserialization of body, for reference, you can find the repo here: https://github.com/TheReprator/AccountBook_Backend/blob/master/lib/testModule/src/main/kotlin/dev/reprator/testModule/KoinClientModule.kt

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for a `ContentNegotiation` class? Take a look at https://ktor.io/docs/serialization.html#implement_custom_serializer, you only need to implement two functions.

Comment: not exactly, but i am looking for dserialization on client end